# Classification of 2-groups with center of index 4

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Can one obtain a classification of 2-groups with *center* of index 4, analogous to the classification of 2-groups with *derived subgroup* of index 4?

Comment: Why are you particularly interested in 2-groups whose center has index 4 -- i.e. why not e.g. index 2 or 8, or 3-groups with center of index 9, etc., etc. -- and what type of answers are you looking for?

Comment: @StefanKohl: Just to nitpick, it's very easy to characterize all groups with center of index 2: they do not exist....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Of course. -- But isn't the trivial characterization a nice characterization?

Comment: A natural framework would be to classify finite groups with center of index $p^2$ (in a sense these, among $p$-groups, are the non-abelian groups with center as large as possible), and such a group being direct product of an abelian group and a $p$-group, we can stick to $p$-groups. Typically for such classifications $p=2$ should be a bit exceptional.

Answer (score 3):

These are the nonabelian central extensions of the Klein four-group by an abelian 2-group.

Comment: Derek: Note that I wrote "central extension". Dihedral 2-groups of order greater than 8 cannot be central extensions of the Klein four-group.

Comment: That's true! I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @Derek: Yes, I agree.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Can you explain a little more about this equivalent description? (This question came up on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2686286/groups-with-large-centers.)

Comment: @Verret It's not correct. I'll delete that comment.

Comment: Isn't it just a restatement of the question? the question is to classify such groups.

Comment: @YCor: I agree, but the new restatement actually provides a cohomological description of such groups,  as the cohomology groups of the Klein four group over abelian groups (regarded as trivial modules) are well known (cf.https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_cohomology_of_Klein_four-group )

Comment: @SalvatoreSiciliano Sure; more precisely you also need to mod out by some equivalence relation (and remove the abelian cases). Possibly the equivalence relation is "modulo action of the automorphism groups of the abelian kernel on the one hand, and of the Klein quotient on the other hand.

Comment: @YCor: That's right, I agree.